How to disable v-autocomplete events for appended icon click
I have a autocomplete input with an appended inner icon that has a click function attached and then clearable is enabled.  If you click clearable the options menu appears and if you click the appended icon the options menu also appears. I do not want these icons to initiate the options menu since a user would not click them and click elsewhere to enable the options. This is my code below. How do I disable the option event for these icons?
<v-autocomplete
                      v-for="(header,index) in headers"
                      :key="index"
                      v-model="header.filtered"
                      class="my-5"
                      clearable
                      chips
                      :label="header.title"
                      :items="getUniqueList(displayedReviews,header.key)"
                      multiple
                      density="compact"
                      variant="outlined"
                      hide-details
                      single-line
                      flat
                      @blur="applyFilters()"
                      :append-inner-icon="header.visible ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                      @click:append-inner="header.visible = !header.visible"
                    >
                    </v-autocomplete>


In vuetify2, you could use preventDefault to prevent the menu options from being opened.
...           
append-icon="mdi-eye"
@click:append="
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
"

I guess you are using the Vuetify3, and it seems this is a bug in vuetify3.
I would suggest you use the append icon instead of using the append-inner icon.
See example: append icon for detailed information

I am using vuetify 3. If you do not mind me asking how do you know its a bug, did you test this out yourself? Thanks!

Because I have tried it out myself, and it works fine in vuetify2, only has this issue in vuetify3

Thank you for the confirmation. Just wanted to make sure I was not implmenting it incorrectly . I also have used it in vuetify 2 as well and no issues. Hopefully they fix it soon. Putting the icon on the outside in my situation does not look as good for my UI.

What's the detail version of your vuetify3?

It is version 3.5.12
